# I have a never-ending debug and don't know what's the matter. The programme has to apply a bilateral filter to the image

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
path="C:\\Users\\NONSTOP.DESKTOP-I55D60P\\Desktop\\labs\\practice\\Image.jpg"
def bilateral_filter(image, d, sigmaColor, sigmaSpace):
    filtered_image = np.zeros_like(image, dtype=np.float32)  
    image = image.astype(np.float32) / 255.0    
    height, width = image.shape
    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            cpixel = image[i, j]
            total_weight = 0.0
            filtered_pixel = np.zeros_like(cpixel)
            for s in range(-d, d+1):
                for t in range(-d, d+1):
                    if i + s >= 0 and i + s < height and j + t >= 0 and j + t < width:
                        spixel = image[i + s, j + t]                   
                        I = np.linalg.norm(spixel - cpixel)
                        a = np.exp(-(I**2) / (2 * (sigmaColor**2)))
                        b = np.exp(-((s**2 + t**2) / (2 * (sigmaSpace**2))))
                        weight = a * b
                        filtered_pixel += spixel * weight
                        total_weight += weight
            
    filtered_image = filtered_image.astype(np.uint8)
    return filtered_image
image= cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
cv2.imshow('Image',image)
cv2.waitkey(5000)
cv2.destoryAllWindows()
filtered_image=bilateral_filter(image,d=9,sigmaColor=75,sigmaSpace=75)
cv2.imshow('FilteredImage',filtered_image)
cv2.waitKey(5000)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The programme does not output the image with bilateral filter. If I try to display the original image, it does and then python closes.

Comment: It will be very helpful if you add the error that you get.

Comment: there is no error, just program exit

Comment: You wrote - "and then python closes with a program response error"

Comment: I meant it closes with the message "python is not responding".

Comment: You need to add a bunch of debugging prints to have a clear idea of how far it's getting, and hopefully isolate the step that's hanging or quiting.  I don't how you are 'debugging'.  For some reason, beginners have a tendency to try "random" fixes, without first getting a clear idea of where's the problem.

Comment: Csn you try to remove the first cv2.destroyAllWindows() and use a waitKey(0) in the end? Btw. the destory is a typi, right? cv2.destoryAllWindows()

Answer (score 0):

You have made a few mistakes. I also think that your image is just big and/or your algorithm is slow. That's why you get the `not responding` error. This is easy to verify. Please read on.

### Typos

```py
cv2.waitkey(5000)
```

should be

```py
cv2.waitKey(5000)
```

or if you ask me,

```py
cv2.waitkey()
```

instead. Please refer to [the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7).

Another typo:

```py
cv2.destoryAllWindows()
```

should be

```py
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Then, for the actual thing. You didn't tell us what you are trying to do but my guess is that you have implemented some kind of filter than you are applying to an image. You would like to apply the filter to the image, then show the original image and the filtered image.

### Suggestions

Move everything in a main function. Makes your code faster.

Next time when you're posting a question please share us also the image that you're using. Makes the testing easier.

I made this image to test your code:

[image]

After I fixed the typos it looks like there are some "real" bugs in your code. The function `bilaterar_filter` does actually *always* return a black image. You don't edit the `filtered_image` in the for loop at all. It's hard for me to guess what you want your function to exactly do but my guess is that this would be what you wanted:

```py
def bilateral_filter(image, d, sigmaColor, sigmaSpace):
    filtered_image = np.zeros_like(image, dtype=np.float32)  
    image = image.astype(np.float32) / 255.0    
    height, width = image.shape

    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            cpixel = image[i, j]
            total_weight = 0.0
            filtered_pixel = np.zeros_like(cpixel)

            for s in range(-d, d+1):
                for t in range(-d, d+1):
                    if i + s >= 0 and i + s < height and j + t >= 0 and j + t < width:
                        spixel = image[i + s, j + t]                   
                        I = np.linalg.norm(spixel - cpixel)
                        a = np.exp(-(I**2) / (2 * (sigmaColor**2)))
                        b = np.exp(-((s**2 + t**2) / (2 * (sigmaSpace**2))))
                        weight = a * b
                        filtered_pixel += spixel * weight
                        total_weight += weight
            filtered_image[i,j] = filtered_pixel
    filtered_image = filtered_image.astype(np.uint8)
    return filtered_image
```

This is the final code using the function above:

```py
def main():
    image= cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    filtered_image=bilateral_filter(image,d=9,sigmaColor=75,sigmaSpace=75)
    cv2.imshow('Image+Filtered',cv2.hconcat([image, filtered_image]))
    cv2.waitKey()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    print("Exiting successfully")

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

and the result:

[image]

If your code still hangs note that for a 1920x1080 picture your algorithm is running 4 `for`-loops for `1920*1080*20*20=829'440'000` times. That's why I'm testing with a small 53x80 picture. But optimizing the code is out of scope for this question.

Please test your code with the code and image on this post and verify if your algorithm works as intended.